# How to import multiple csvfiles to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import, delimiter, quotes

I have 3000 csv files that are " delimited and , separated. Each is named after the server the data was collected from.  I need to import them into a database to allow me to work with the data.

For an individual file I've tried :

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword --local-infile mydatabase -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/downloads/test/reports/mytestcsvfile.csv' INTO TABLE results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES FIELDS FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\' "
```

and this works fine except that every data element is enclosed in quotes.  If I add

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

then the " in that parameter stops the import working and just gives me a > prompt.

If I escape the " with

```
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
```

then I get an error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\'' at line 1
```

I'll need to enclose the whole lot in something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES= /root/downloads/smtptest/reports/
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "processing $f..."
  mysql -uuser -ppassword --local-infile mydatabase -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/downloads/test/reports/$f' INTO TABLE results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES FIELDS FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\' "
done
```

How can I run the import and strip the ".  Mysqlimport looks to be ruled out as it imports into a table based on filename, not something I want.

And...

To allow me to run it for each file at the moment I'm having to run this first:

```
for f in file*.csv; do echo ":" $f ":"; sed -i "s/^/\"$f\",/" "$f";  done
```

This adds each server name (the filename) to the start of each line in each file so that that becomes part of the record in the database.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was using "fields" multiple times, to define the enclosed, terminated and escaped by parameters.  When I removed that it all started working

This worked :

```
!/bin/bash
for filename in /root/downloads/smtptest/reportsmod/*.csv; do
 echo "processing $filename"
 mysql -uuser -ppassword --local-infile smtpsslcheck -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
done
```